# Data Access Pattern Like Repository but Not Completely

Tags: c#, asp.net, design-patterns, repository-pattern, data-access-layer

I'm working on a project with a system that holds data and I'm thinking about using a data access approach to get data to hand it off to my components on the presentation side of things. I'm thinking of this as an N-tier architecture. Here's my thought:

> Presentation layer (WebForms and User Controls)
>
> ```
>    \/
> ```
>
> Data access layer (this is where my question is)
>
> ```
>    \/
> ```
>
> Business objects (a C# class for each entity in the system)
>
> ```
>    \/
> ```
>
> Existing APIs to get data from database (MS SQL-driven)

In my DAL, I want to use a particular API mechanism from the system to get the business objects so I can pass them to my presentation components. I am aware of the repository pattern where I create various utility repository classes to "get a bunch of the X business objects". E.g. say I have a business object called `Article`, I could have an `ArticleRepository` and my "Article listing page" would call that repository and get me a collection of `Article`. This is nice, but might be overkill at the DAL for me. Is there a name of doing something else like just having a `static GetAll()` method on my business object? So isntead of:

```
var repo = new ArticleRepository();
IEnumerable<Article> articles = repo.GetAll();
```

I'm thinking something simple like this:

```
IEnumerable<Article> articles = Article.GetAll();
```

Where the `Article` class is both my business object with relevant properties and even helper methods, but also has a `static GetAll()` method. Is there a name for this approach? Is it a bad idea to create this slimmed down pseudo-repository?

I ask all this because simply put, I will have LOTS of repository classes to do this because I have lots of business objects, all with unique queries to get them from the system.

Comment: I think your business objects should be separated from your data access, therefore you shouldn't include data access methods in your business classes

Comment: Coding data access behavior into your business objects makes it very hard to make changes later on, breaks the Separation Of Concerns principle etc. The purpose of the Article class is to represent an article, not deal with persisting itself in the datastore. I would strongly suggest you have a look at Entity Framework or some other Object/Relational mapper for data storage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know about the name of your architecture, but IMHO DAL should take care of persistence thus dealing directly with DB API.

From my experience, there's no excuse for thinking that some good practice is overkill :)
Generic repository with EF is pretty simple to implement and will make you smile in the future.

Comment: Other than a repository are there any other data access patterns to use?

Comment: Not sure about what you need. Do you have legacy application or starting from scratch? Is it possible to use ORM?